# How to change Kendo Excel Button Content Text

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which has Excel export function. It produces a" Export to Excel" texted button and i want to change its text like "Send to Excel".

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).ToList())
.Name("Grid")

.Columns(columns =>
{
    //columns.Bound(p => p.BirimAd).Title("Birim").Width(500);
    columns.Bound(p => p.SehirAd).Title("Şehir").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).Width(200);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Value).Title("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).Width(200);
    //columns.Bound(p => p.Avg).Title("Avg").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).Width(200);
})
  .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())

.Sortable()

.Excel(excel => excel
    .FileName("Rapor.xlsx")
    .Filterable(true)
    .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Report"))
)

.ColumnMenu()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()

.Read(read => read.Action("Excel_Export_Read", "Report"))
)
    )
```

and excel button is producing like that:

```
<button class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel"><span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Export to Excel</button>
```

I am trying this css:

```
 <style>

     .k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel
     {
         content:"Send to Excel";
     }
     .k-icon k-i-excel
     {
         content:"Send to Excel"
     }

 </style>
```

But it looks like same text. How can i change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using custom command and calling export via javascript api

Razor :

```
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Custom("Export").Text("Send to Excel").Click("exportExcel"))
```

Javascript:

```
function exportExcel() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.saveAsExcel();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I override the text in bound event:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  Events(eventes => {
     eventes.DataBound("bound"); 
  })
  .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
  .Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("Test.xlsx")
        .Filterable(true)
        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("TestExcel", "Export"))
    )
```

then in bound event:

```
<script>
function bound(e) {
   ...
   $(".k-grid-excel").html('<span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Exportar a Excel');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the API has changed over the years, below code works for me in 2019

```
  .ToolBar(tb => tb.Excel().Text("Any Text") )
```